# PreferenceActivity custom ListView select item background color

Tags: android, android-listview, preferenceactivity

I would like to change a default orange background color of the listview item when I select it of my `PreferenceActivity`, but I am not sure how to do that.

I could make it for normal `Activity` with `listview` by creating a custom adapter and inflate a layout for listview item where could I add `android:background="@drawable/listview_item_selector"` for root layout, but how could I do that for the `PreferenceActivity`?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Create a theme and apply it only to preference activity.

Comment: Could you write me how should I do that? I am new in android and when I apply that theme 
<style name="PreferenceListView" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/listview_item_selector</item>
    </style>
then all acitivity changed not only listview item, also all listview background is changed.